# What is a "roll-off"?

Tags: nouns, meaning-in-context

> Studies show a substantial profitability roll-off.

What does "roll-off" mean? Is it another word for "decrease"?

Comment: Let's see [what Google says](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=roll+off+definition) about it... If there is something that you do not understand about it after looking it up, please add to your question.

Comment: The technical definition of a "roll-off" (from wikipedia) doesn't help me, since it is a term from electrical network analysis, which doesn't make any sense when used in the sentence above. I'd like to know what "roll-off" might mean in the context of my sentence.

Comment: It looks like a coined expression to me. English does permit writers to create language as they express themselves.

Comment: From analogy with the signal definition, it would seem to mean a reduction to zero at some point. For a signal, this would be at a frequency that is past a high or low threshold. For profitability perhaps it is after a specific event or due to a specific cause. Since you provide no context, it's hard to guess.

Comment: @Drew Thanks, that already helped me. The context actually does have to do with some kind of frequency.

Comment: *Provide the context* and perhaps someone will help you more. People generally are willing to help here, but they don't necessarily want to strain themselves guessing what's involved.

Answer (score 1):

Roll-off is the steepness of a transmission function with frequency, particularly in electrical network analysis, and most especially in connection with filter circuits in the transition between a passband and a stopband. It is most typically applied to the insertion loss of the network, but can in principle be applied to any relevant function of frequency, and any technology, not just electronics. It is usual to measure roll-off as a function of logarithmic frequency, consequently, the units of roll-off are either decibels per decade (dB/decade), where a decade is a 10-times increase in frequency, or decibels per octave (dB/8ve), where an octave is 2-times increase in frequency.

The concept of roll-off stems from the fact that in many networks roll-off tends towards a constant gradient at frequencies well away from the cut-off point of the frequency curve. Roll-off enables the cut-off performance of such a filter network to be reduced to a single number. Note that roll-off can occur with decreasing frequency as well as increasing frequency, depending on the bandform of the filter being considered: for instance a low-pass filter will roll-off with increasing frequency, but a high-pass filter or the lower stopband of a band-pass filter will roll-off with decreasing frequency. For brevity, this article describes only low-pass filters. This is to be taken in the spirit of prototype filters; the same principles may be applied to high-pass filters by interchanging phrases such as "above cut-off frequency" and "below cut-off frequency".

Answer (score 0):

This appears to mean a substantial drop in profitability.  The word "roll-off" appears to involve the action of an object (profitability is used as the object here, although it technically isn't an object) rolling off a table, cliff, or other height and dropping to the floor or ground.  So if the profitability rolled off a cliff, it will drop to a lower point than it was at previously; in this case, it is substantially lower than before.